# Is it possible to create non recursive destructor in stack like container?

Tags: c++, stack

I'm writing a code in C++ with container similar to Stack.

```
class Stack {
public:
    int data;
    Stack *next;
    void push();
    void pop();
    ~Stack() {
        delete next;
    }

};
```

The problem is in recursive destructor. If i push hundreds of thousands elements, destructor crashes to stack overflow. Is it possible to change it in non recursive way?

Comment: Yes , iterate trough all the nodes and add them to a `std::set`. after that delete the objects from the set only.

Comment: Your class-definition is recursive itself, having a `Stack*` as a member. If the stack has to be implemented as a linked list, use nodes to do so. Or just use `std::stack`.

Comment: You may want to have a *StackRoot* class.

Comment: Thank you for very fast answers. I will implement my Stack as a node and add Stack class that controls nodes.

Comment: FYI, in generic programming a _stack_ is not itself a type of container, it is a container adaptor: a different interface on top  of a container. Anything that can push back, pop back, and get back can be the underlying container of a stack, such as `std::vector`, `std::deque`, and `std::list`. These containers can also just be treated as a stack even without a restrictive interface

Comment: @mlecz Yes, even though it seems intuitive and simple to combine stack and node, you stumbled on a practical issue of maximum stack size.  Mind you that this is an issue for a lot of recursive programming where you can't define an end or where no tail optimization is done.

Comment: @Dave: That's true in C++. I haven't heard Container Adapter in general computer science, though.

Comment: @phresnel I didn't say general computer science, I said in _generic programming_... which only applies to a few languages. You're right that 'Container Adapter' is just what C++ calls it; but I think generic programming is just more more progressed in C++ than other languages, so it's hard to talk about it without C++ specifics.

Comment: @Dave: LISP, Haskell, D, Python, Ruby, Javascript, Java, C#, even C, to just name a few. All have generic programming. While I see that you are talking about C++, newcomers might be confused, especially by a _FYI_-prefixed comment, and think this applies to generic programming in general :)

Comment: @phresnel The state of generic programming in different languages is not equal. Like I said, it's more progressed in C++. D and C++ are first class citizens, C# et. al. are 2nd, and Haskell et. al. are 3rd class.

Comment: @Dave: I never heard of that definition. What exactly makes Haskell "3rd class" for example, when in Haskell, functions are generic by default and you have to put extra-effort in to make them non-generic? In this respect, are you equating Metaprogramming with Generic Programming? Then LISP would be first class, D second, and C++(11) just third. Also, `std::stack` is just one possible implementation that happens to be a container adapter; this does not really imply a rule like "in [C++] generic programming, it's an adapter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initially built a "recursive" class. Though it would be better to redesign your class and include internal private structure named as for example Node neverthelsee this code will help you to escape recursive calls of destructors for your original class.

```
~Stack() 
{
    Stack *next = this->next;
    while ( next )
    {
       Stack *current = next;
       next = next->next;
       current->next = nullptr;
       delete current;
    }
}
```

Comment: While deleting current, this destructor will be called.

Comment: @stefaanv Yes, it will be called but at least there will not be a recursion because current->next is set to nullptr.

Comment: Still, it's a brittle solution and needing this should hint that a better solution should be found (stack/node separation in this case).

Comment: @stefaanv I agree but applying to the original design of the class it can help to escape recursive calls of destructors. It helps to understand what is behind the scene.:)

Comment: @stefaanv It is also an interesting example of convertion a recursion to an iteration.

Answer (score 4):

A natural solution is to have an internal `Node` structure which contains the actual data and the linkage. Then the `Stack` class just have a pointer to the first node in the list, and can easily iterate over the list to delete each node.